# Core-Data Check Box Cell with many-to-many data

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, checkbox, cocoa-bindings

i've got a Core-Data model like this (just an example):

[image: Model]

Now i'd like to have a window where a user can select the ingredients of the drink from every ingredient. like this:

[image: User Interface]

How can i achieve this?

Thanks,
Thomas Günzel

Comment: Perfect use case for Cocoa bindings.  Set `NSArrayController` entity to `Ingredient` and bind its `arrangedObjects` property to the table view content binding.  Then the second column text field is bound to `objectValue.name`

Comment: and how do i get the selected to be saved under the drinks, ingredients?

Comment: you would probably have to extend the `Ingredient` entity with a `selected` attributed (possibly transient?) then use some sort of delegate protocol on the popover to save selected ingredients to the represented drink.