# Core Data and bindings - binding checkbox to result of many-to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

**Core Data model**

I have a many-to-many relationship between two of the principal entities; call them **Item** and **Tag**. There will be a large number of Documents. Each may have 0 to an arbitrary number of tags.

Each **Item** entity relevantly has an attribute called *name*, and a to-many relationship to Tag called *tags*. Each **Tag** entity relevantly has an attribute called *name*, and a to-many relationship to Item called *items*.

To display them, within the same window, I have: (i) an NSTableView (*itemTableView*), fed by an NSArrayController (*itemArrayController*), showing all Items; and (ii) an NSTableView (*tagTableView*), fed by a different NSArrayController (*tagArrayController*) showing all Lists.

**tagTableView**

In the tagTableView, the Table View is bound to tagArrayController, with controllerKey arrangedObjects.

There is only a single table column. The textfield in it is bound to Table Cell View, to model key path objectValue.name. That works so far; it displays all of the lists as expected, and sorts properly when I add a sort descriptor.

Everything has been set up using interface builder in Xcode.

**The problem**

I have added a checkbox into the tagTableView, in the same table column as the textfield. I am trying to implement two things:

1. The checkbox should be checked if the user has previously associated the Item with the relevant Tag. If not, the checkbox should be unchecked.
2. If the user checks an unchecked checkbox, I want to establish a relationship between the two; if the user unchecked a checked checkbox, I want to break that relationship.

The underlying behavior pattern is that the user will not necessarily have control over the tags and may not be able to create them. They are to choose from existing tags, and therefore should be able to see which ones exist, and be able to check/uncheck those that apply.

However, I can't see how to implement this.

**Part solutions so far**

I can see a possible way to do at least the first task programmatically, roughly along these lines:

1. Monitor tableViewSelectionDidChange for itemTableView
2. For a change, update the data source for tagTableView manually, and work out checkbox state by checking them for those Tags which relate to the Item entity that has just been selected, and otherwise unchecking them

However, this looks likely to add complexity, and ideally I would like to do this with bindings if possible.

I have reviewed the Apple Core Data and Bindings references, all the Cocoa books I have, stack overflow and I've also done extensive googling. I have found lots of similar questions (e.g. http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/Mar/msg00164.html) but no answers.

I've also found a way that might work programmatically, but which seems to be like my idea above, at the expense of being able to use bindings (e.g. http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates)

The only relevant question on this site -- [Core-Data Check Box Cell with many-to-many data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372874/core-data-check-box-cell-with-many-to-many-data) -- is not answered to a level that I can make use of.

It would seem to me that this should be a prime candidate for bindings. I should be able to ask the itemArrayController what Tags (if any) have a relation to its selected item, and then set the checkbox to ticked if it matches the relevant Tag, and unset it if it doesn't. I would expect I should be able to do this within the bindings for the checkbox itself, in interface builder. But I can't work out what model key path or binding to use, or what to set the cocoa bindings for the checkbox to. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks